# angularjs directive template binding for openlayers does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

My angular directive is about openlayers map application.

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <map-container></map-container>
</div>
```

Angular [Working code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ywo20y2L/):

```
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").controller("MapContainerController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.map = new ol.Map({});
});

angular.module("app").directive("mapContainer", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        "transclude": true,
        "controller": "MapContainerController",
        "link": function (scope) {
            var map = scope.map;
            map.setTarget(scope.targetElement || "map");
            map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }));
            map.setView(new ol.View({
                zoom: 3,
                center: [0, 0]
            }));
        },
        "template": '<div id="map" class="map" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
});
```

But I want to use scope parameter for directive map element name like following code: [demo version is here](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ywo20y2L/1/).

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <map-container  target-element="map"></map-container>
</div>
```

But this does not work.

```
angular.module("app").directive("mapContainer", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        "transclude": true,
        "scope": {
            "targetElement": "@"
        },
        "controller": "MapContainerController",
        "link": function (scope) {
            var map = scope.map;
            map.setTarget(scope.targetElement || "map");
            map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }));
            map.setView(new ol.View({
                zoom: 3,
                center: [0, 0]
            }));
        },
        "template": '<div id="{{targetElement}}" class="map" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
});
```

Everything looks like fine but it does not work. I could not understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to wrap your directive code in $timeout, so that template is displayed with id, before creating map.

```
angular.module("app").directive("mapContainer", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        "transclude": true,
        "scope": {
            "targetElement": "@"
        },
        "controller": "MapContainerController",
        "link": function (scope) {
            var map = scope.map;

            $timeout(function() {
               map.setTarget(scope.targetElement || "map");
               map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Tile({
                   source: new ol.source.OSM()
               }));
               map.setView(new ol.View({
                  zoom: 3,
                  center: [0, 0]
               }));

            });
                    },
        "template": '<div id="{{targetElement}}" class="map" ng-transclude></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: and i did it too and it work, you can see it log 'div' https://jsfiddle.net/y68v64xw/

Comment: Console logs the result you right but map does not appear. This shows map: https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ywo20y2L/  But this does not show the map: https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/ywo20y2L/1/

Comment: I think you just forgot to add a $timeout, so ol was not finding your div it was not loading it, just edited my answer, changed it a little bit, because i was testing diffferent things

Comment: How does ol find my div used $timout? or how does it find not used scope parameter?

Comment: I think it was calling the map before angular change your directive template id, so openlayer target was missing. $timeout wait the end of the digest loop to trigger, so your directive template div has its id, openlayer can now find the div and create the map, see edit.